# No response from content script for contextmenu chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have already developed chrome extension for context menu and it worked.After the change over of new API by google chrome,my extension is not working.I saw the documents need to change the deprecated API. But no luck!
Here are the files,

**manifest.json**

```
    {  
    "manifest_version": 2,  
    "name": "ClickRight Plugin",  
    "version": "1.0",  
    "description": "Clickright utility for Chrome Browser",  
    "permissions":["contextMenus","tabs","https://www.gmail.com"],  
    "content_scripts" : [  
     {  
    "matches" : [  
    "http://*/*",  
    "https://*/*"  
    ],  
    "js" : ["chromeplug.js"]  
    }  
    ],  
    "background":  
    {  
    "page":"background.html"  
    }  
    }
```

**background.html**

Included two scripts, clickright.js and chromeplug.js

**chromeplug.js**

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {  
if (request.method == "getHtml") {  
..   
sendResponse({key:value});});  
chrome.contextMenus.create({  
"title": "Trace CAL Log",  
"contexts": ["page", "selection"]  
});  
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function()  
{  
chrome.tabs.query({  
active: true,  
currentWindow: true},  
function(tabs) {  
chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id,{method:"getHtml"}, function(response) {  
var id=response.key;  
getChromeLogs(id,tabs[0].url);  
});  
});
```

**clickright.js**
getChromeLogs(LogId,URL){}

On clicking the context menu nothing happens!Guess I have included all neccessary API. May be wrong with the placing of API in files.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: any errors? is handler being fired? is query returning results? any specifics?

Comment: I get this error message in the console before i do right click in the expected page "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'create' of undefined".I did not miss the entry for contextMenu in permissions key too.Background.html does not throw any error.handler has not been fired(alert statement inside chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){} is not executed).No response i could see when i click the contextmenu.Got stuck with my development.Thanks @Maciej!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `chrome.contextMenus.create` should go into background.js, not content script.

Comment: yes,that resolved the error!Thanks much but the functionality is not working.My requirement is to get the data from a page source of a web page(it is in chromeplug.js) and passing that information to background.js for further processing.Here for an website e.g www.gmail.com ,on clicking context menu i get into the page which is expected.Then for the different flow say for login error page of gmail.com ,when i click the contextmenu it doesnt works.Hope you understand the issue @Maciej

Comment: I mean when one resultant page of right click is open, the other web page right click result page is not opening.But the second flow page gives me result when the first flow page result is closed.

Comment: permissions maybe?
like `https://www.gmail.com/*` (missing star?)
maaan, I'm not doing your work :P

Comment: :)sorry to bug you again!It doesn't seem to be permission problem as i get the result of website child pages https://www.gmail.com/*,when the result of other pages are closed.Also I have included (/*) in permissions.Right click works for any page when the result for other pages are closed!

Comment: I'm doing paid services if you are interested